# XCTest and CoreData

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-data, xctest

I am trying to Unit test my model in Xcode 5 by using the XCTest classes and methods.

Because my model classes inherit of `managedObject`, I can't just instantiate (alloc/init) them and call the getters and setters or the methods I need to test.
I need to create them by using the `NSEntityDescription` and use a `managedObjectContext`.

That is with this point that I get troubles.
I don't know where and how to create the `managedObjectContext` for unit tests purpose.

If anyone has some advice or code examples, it will be very helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use an in memory store to for my unit tests and create all the entities within that.

This class method can be placed in `TestsHelper.m`

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContextForTests {
    static NSManagedObjectModel *model = nil;
    if (!model) {
        model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:[NSBundle allBundles]];
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
    NSPersistentStore *store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:nil];
    NSAssert(store, @"Should have a store by now");

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;

    return moc;
}
```

This works for me because I use Dependency Injection to pass my moc around rather than using a singleton.

Comment: Thanks, because I am not using Dependency Injection (yet), I did put your code in my tests classes `setUp` and `[moc rollback]` in the `tearDown`. It work well. What do you use for Dependency Injection ?

Comment: I set up my controllers so that they have a property which I set to the managed object context.

Comment: Can you add an example of how you implemented the dependency injection?

Comment: @Abizern where does TestsHelper.m belong?  Under a project's test directory where the XCTestCase subclasses go?  If so, should it be a normal "Objective-C class" having .h and .m files or should it be an "Objective-C test case class" having no actual test cases?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: It tells me "`"NSInvalidArgumentException", "Can't merge models with two different entities named '<redacted>'"`"

Answer (score 12):

I concur with @Abizern:  pass an instance to a `NSManagedObjectContext` around in your code instead of relying on your app delegate, a global variable, or a custom helper singleton.

### Dependency Injection

If you know that some controller will need access, add a `NSManagedObjectContext` parameter to  its init method and keep a strong reference to it:

```
@interface SomeController : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSManagedObjectContext *context;
- (instancetype)initWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
@end
```

This is the minimum requirement to do "dependency injection". You don't need a fancy framework to do the injection for you. Instead, in your app you assign your usual `NSManagedObjectContext` instance which probably uses a SQLite store. In your tests, you create a separate `NSManagedObjectContext` with an in-memory store and pass it to `SomeController`. This would even work with (partial) mocks using OCMock.

There are some good examples at objc.io #4, especially Chris Eidhof's example app:  http://www.objc.io/issue-4/full-core-data-application.html

### How to access a MOC

Looking at the [objc.io example code at GitHub](https://github.com/objcio/issue-4-full-core-data-application/), you'll see a [`PersistentStack`](https://github.com/objcio/issue-4-full-core-data-application/blob/master/NestedTodoList/PersistentStack.m) helper class which takes care of initializing the managed object context for your application.  Chris uses an abstract test case subclass to provide a [testing context](https://github.com/objcio/issue-4-full-core-data-application/blob/master/NestedTodoListTests/NestedTodoListTestCase.m).

The overall guideline is this:

1. **Don't rely on a singleton helper class throughout the code** because it's hard to replace its context with a test context. That's a peculiarity I have discovered and which is due to XCTest being "injected" into the running app code.  There were working examples on the web, but they didn't do what I expected with Xcode 5.1 and XCTest.
2. Instead, prepare a `NSManagedObjectContext` once where appropriate. Pass managed objects around and **use the managed objects to get access to the context.**

Florian Kugler [states it this way:](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-models-and-model-objects.html#managed_objects)

> Managed objects are supposed to be passed around in the application, crossing at least the model-controller barrier, and potentially even the controller-view barrier. The latter is somewhat more controversial though, and can be abstracted in a better way by e.g. defining a protocol to which an object must conform in order to be consumed by a certain view, or by implementing configuration methods in a view category that bridge the gap from the model object to the specifics of the view.
>
> Anyway, we shouldn’t limit managed objects to the model layer and pull out their data into different structures as soon as we want to pass them around. Managed objects are first-class citizens in a Core Data app and we should use them accordingly. For example, managed objects should be passed between view controllers to provide them with the data they need.
>
> In order to access the managed object context we often see code like this in view controllers:
>
> ```
> NSManagedObjectContext *context = 
>   [(MyApplicationDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
> ```
>
> If you already pass a model object to the view controller, it’s much better to access the context directly via this object:
>
> ```
> NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.myObject.managedObjectContext;
> ```
>
> This removes the hidden dependency on the application delegate, and makes it much more readable and also easier to test.

This is the best overall advice I got. Now I'm able to test Core Data usage where I need to. Previously, accessing the context via global singleton class (custom class or app delegate) was convenient to use in production, but proves difficult to validate in tests.

Answer (score 3):

#### Swift

`NSManagedObjectContext` extension that creates an in-memory `CoreData` stack for tests

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    
    class func contextForTests() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        // Get the model
        let model = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: Bundle.allBundles)!
        
        // Create and configure the coordinator
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)
        try! coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: nil, options: nil)
        
        // Setup the context
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return context
    }
    
}
```

Then use it in your tests:

```
class YourTests: XCTestCase {
    
    private var context: NSManagedObjectContext?

    override func setUp() {
        self.context = NSManagedObjectContext.contextForTests()
    }

    // And use it in your tests
}
```