# XCTest with Core Data

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-data, xctest

1. Do XCTests run in parallel (that is, are multiple tests allowed to run at the same moment?).  Consider a single test file with multiple tests, and multiple test files with multiple tests each.
2. If core data is used in some of the components being tested, and tests can run in parallel, what is the correct method of using the core data in the tests? For example, the test should start with a 'clean' data store, and then add objects as needed, then get tested based off of the contents of the store.  It sounds like if they all use the same managed object context/store they'll be pointing to the same data and thus be at risk for colliding with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Each XCTest method is run sequentially (one at the moment)
2. To test Core Data I often create in memory Persistance Store, here you have good snipped: [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460533/2069114) using this kind of MOC you always have clear core data state

Please check also this [Rays tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/101306/unit-testing-tutorial-mocking-objects)

Answer (score 2):

Tests are run serially on the main thread of the test runner process. However nothing automatically guards against you starting asynchronous actions which could extend into the execution of a future test case.

For example a call to `perfomBlock` on a `NSManagedObjectContext` is not guaranteed to execute before the next test starts. This can be especially problematic if your tests trigger saves which propagate asynchronously to parent managed object contexts.

I've found it valuable to write easily testable code which means injecting the managed object contexts or other dependencies into the code under test. That should allow you to build an independent Core Data stack for each test case rather than unexpectedly sharing some global state in a single context. Then you just need to beware of overly permissive notification observers which don't bother to check the sender of a `NSNotification` (i.e. when observing `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`s).

Comment: "For example a call to perfomBlock on a NSManagedObjectContext is not guaranteed to execute before the next test starts." What about if you have expectations in the test? Won't the test wait until the expectation is fulfilled before completing?

Comment: Possibly, if you are using `XCTestExpectation` or an equivalent async assertion. For example you might be able to write a test tearDown method which waits for async events to finish before moving on to the next test. Exactly how you determine that such async actions have finished depends on your app and can be tricky. I find it's usually safer to avoid sharing state in the first place if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

1.Test cases are executed one by one and test files as well.

2.Your core data managed object context should be created by importing you app in your test case(@testable import product_name) file and access the core date objects in test case files.All the test cases will be run independently.
So As you mentioned the test should start with a 'clean' data store, and then add objects as needed, then get tested based off of the contents of the store.yes,this is correct way.make sure core data managed objects are created in test files.test cases can be tested in Test Navigation section.

Answer (score 0):

Full example:

```
import XCTest
import CoreData
@testable import MyApp

class MyAppTests: XCTestCase {
    var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer!
    
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        persistentContainer = Persistence(inMemory: true).container
    }
    
    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
        persistentContainer = nil
    }
    
   
    func testAsyncCoreDataFunction() async throws {
        let context = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
        // Call an asynchronous function
        let result = await asyncCoredDataInsert(context: context)
        XCTAssertEqual(result.count, 1)
        
        let result2 = try await asyncCoredDataFetch(context: context)
        XCTAssertEqual(result2.count, 1)
    }
    
    func asyncCoredDataInsert(context: NSManagedObjectContext) async -> [Person] {
        var result = [Person]()
        
        await context.perform {
            let item = Person(context: context)
            item.name = "John"
            result.append(item)
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
    func asyncCoredDataFetch(context: NSManagedObjectContext) async throws -> [Person] {
        var result = [Person]()
        
        try await context.perform {
            let request = Person.fetchRequest()
            result = try context.fetch(request)
        }
        
        return result
    }
}


struct Persistence {
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyApp")
        
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}
```